# SHA2_256 direct comparison

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hash

I would like to find out whether given SHA 256 hash has been already stored in database.

```
create table #tmpH (input VARCHAR(20), hsh VARBINARY(8000))

insert into #tmpH values('Hello', HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'Hello'))
insert into #tmpH values('Internet', HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'Internet'))

input       hsh
Hello       0x185F8DB32271FE25F561A6FC938B2E264306EC304EDA518007D1764826381969
Internet    0x57E8A431DEEC0D70DA0A26EA3392E59688B11B79EDFD04E9DA823B16BCD1D4D7

select * from #tmpH where hsh = '0x185F8DB32271FE25F561A6FC938B2E264306EC304EDA518007D1764826381969'                            --Nope
select * from #tmpH where hsh = CAST('0x185F8DB32271FE25F561A6FC938B2E264306EC304EDA518007D1764826381969' as varbinary(8000))   --Nope
select * from #tmpH where cast(hsh as VARCHAR(100)) = '0x185F8DB32271FE25F561A6FC938B2E264306EC304EDA518007D1764826381969'      --Nope
select * from #tmpH where CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), hsh, 2) = '0x185F8DB32271FE25F561A6FC938B2E264306EC304EDA518007D1764826381969'  --Nope
select * from #tmpH where hsh = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'Hello')          --Works
```

How can I compare two hashes made by the same algorithm when I don't have the original value and can't hash it myself?

I am working with MS SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not tried the simplest (and, incidentally, working) method:

`select * from #tmpH 
where hsh = 0x185F8DB32271FE25F561A6FC938B2E264306EC304EDA518007D1764826381969`

Management Studio recognizes `0x` as prefix for binary data in hexadecimal format.

Comment: This feels awkward... I guess it's one of those you live you learn moments. Thanks.

Comment: It's not "awkward" at all, @Bendom . `'1'` and `1` aren't the same values, one is an `int` the other a `varchar`. The same holds true for other data types. `0x01` and `'0x01'` aren't the same either, they are different data types. The key thing, however, is that when you convert a `varchar` to a `varbinary` **implicitly** it will be converted to the `varbinary` representation of that `varchar`, not the `varbinary` it represents. Otherwise you'd get errors like "Cannot convert varchar value "hello" to varbinary" with a clause like `0x68656C6C6F = 'hello'`.

Comment: @Larnu What I ment is I feel awkward for not even thinking of this solution and spending so much time trying to figure it out. Now that I see it, it makes sense. :)

Answer (score 1):

The **`varchar`** value `'0x185F8DB32271FE25F561A6FC938B2E264306EC304EDA518007D1764826381969'` as a `varbinary`is *not* the value `0x185F8DB32271FE25F561A6FC938B2E264306EC304EDA518007D1764826381969`. If you actually try casting this, you'll find this out very quickly:

```
SELECT CAST('0x185F8DB32271FE25F561A6FC938B2E264306EC304EDA518007D1764826381969' AS varbinary(100)) AS B;

B
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x307831383546384442333232373146453235463536314136464339333842324532363433303645433330344544413531383030374431373634383236333831393639
```

If you are casting a `varchar` that represents a literal `varbinary` you need to use `CONVERT` and a style code:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(100),'0x185F8DB32271FE25F561A6FC938B2E264306EC304EDA518007D1764826381969',1) AS B;

B
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x185F8DB32271FE25F561A6FC938B2E264306EC304EDA518007D1764826381969
```

If, however, this is parametrised, just don't wrap your value in single quotes:

```
SELECT *
FROM #tmpH
WHERE hsh = 0x185F8DB32271FE25F561A6FC938B2E264306EC304EDA518007D1764826381969
```